# View doesn't work onclick a button in backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a view that contain multiple buttons do difference action.

```
var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({
   initialize: function() {

   },
   events : {
       'click #addToWL' : 'addWishList'
   },
   addWishList : function(){
        var _wishList = new WishList();
        _wishList.set({
           "ID" : 0,
           "Name" : "",
           "CustomerID" : 106,
           "Type" : 0,
           "LastUpdated" : "\/Date(1383152400000+0700)\/",
           "WishlistDetail" : [
               {
                   "ID" : 0,
                   "WishListID" : 0,
                   "ItemID" : 22776,
                   "Quantity" : 2,
                   "LastUpdated" : "\/Date(1383152400000+0700)\/"
               }
           ]
       });
       _wishList.save();
       var _wlView = new WishListView({model:_wishList});
   },
   render : function(){
       this.$el.html(homePanel);
       $("#containernewpromotion").html(promotionItem);
   }
});
return HomeView;
```

Here is the WishList view in another file :

```
var WishList = Backbone.View.extend({

    tagName: 'ul',

    initialize:function(){
        console.log("initialize wish list view");
    },

    render: function(){
        this.$el.empty();
        var wishlistView = _.template(WishListTemplate);
        this.$el.append(wishlistView);
    }
});
return WishList;
```

Here's the WishList model :

```
define(["underscore" , "backbone"],function(_ , Backbone){

var WishList = Backbone.Model.extend({
    url  :'//path to REST AddWishList',
    idAttribute: 'ID'
});

var _wishList = new WishList();
_wishList.set({
    "ID" : 0,
    "Name" : "",
    "CustomerID" : 106,
    "Type" : 0,
    "LastUpdated" : "\/Date(1383152400000+0700)\/",
    "WishlistDetail" : [
        {
            "ID" : 0,
            "WishListID" : 0,
            "ItemID" : 22776,
            "Quantity" : 2,
            "LastUpdated" : "\/Date(1383152400000+0700)\/"
        }
    ]
});

  _wishList.save();
  return WishList;
});
```

1. When I click on `#addToWL` button in `HomeView`, the `initialize` function in `WishList` view is working, but `addWishList` function didn't.
2. How can I call the `WishList` model to execute, when I click on `#addToWL` in `HomeView`.

I'm just starting with Backbone.js, Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Do you have duplicate `#addToWL`? `id` attributes must be unique. And what does the HTML look like?

Comment: @muistooshort : Only one `#addToWL` in the html template of require.js text! plugin, `<form class="addToCart-form">
            
            <input type="button" id="addToWL" class="addToWL" value="Add To WishList" />
        </form>`

Comment: So `#addToWl` isn't inside the WishList `el`?

Comment: There is no WishList `el` :/

Comment: You can't have a view without an `el`. Backbone will create one for you and the view's `el` is where the events are bound.

Comment: Ohhh... so due to my view that I show above, could you tell me where is the WishList `el`.

Comment: The `el` would be nowhere on the page unless you've added it yourself.

Comment: If so, could `.addToCart-form` be the Wish List `el`?

Comment: That seems like a reasonable choice. Whatever needs to handle events on `#addToWL` needs to have `#addToWL` inside its `el`.

Comment: @muistooshort : After I added `el` and `render` function, `addWishList` function is working. So how can I call the WishList model to execute, when I click on #addToWL in HomeView.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot add a comment so I put my thought as an answer here.

The problem is in this statement:

```
this.$el.html("tsest");
```

Because your wishlist has only "tsest" in it, I don't think you can expect Backbone to bind an event handler on the button that does not exist in your el.

Comment: But I specified `el: '#webbodycontainer'` , and the button is in that `el`.

Comment: @Domo: But `this.$el.html(...)` would then replace the content of `el`.

Answer (score 0):

1. This is because `#addToWL` is probably not contained into your `WishList(View)` HTML/template (as noted by @chfw and @mu is too short)
2. You need to instantiate your `WishList(Model)` inside `HomeView.addWishList`

### About 1.

As a result the `#addToWL` click event is never triggered inside that View and the `WishList(View).addWishList`  method never gets called.

Thoughts (just my opinion):

- I wouldn't put the `#addToWL` button inside the `WishList(View)`
  anyways (as it seems to me that it is "physically" outside this `View`)
- So the `'click #addToWL' : 'addWishList'` event handler should only be present in `HomeView`, not in `WishList(View)` anymore
- Your `WishList(View)` shouldn't declare the property `el: '#webbodycontainer'` as this element seems to be the entire container of the page...
- But it should rather declare its own, smaller, more contained, element (a `<ul>` list would make sense here!)
- And `HomeView` should declare it instead... As `HomeView` is in charge of the whole container of the page.

### About 2.

BTW you are never instantiating your `WishList(Model)` but only passing the *reference* to the `WishList` constructor:

```
var _wlView = new WishListView({model:WishList});
```

You need to pass an instance of `WishList(Model)` to the `View`:

```
var _wlView = new WishListView({model:new WishList()});
```

---

So that would give something like that:

```
define(["underscore" , "backbone", "app/models/wishlist"], function(_, Backbone, WishList){
  var HomeView = Backbone.View.extend({

     el: '#webbodycontainer',
     events : {
         'click #addToWL' : 'addWishList'
     },
     addWishList : function(){

          var _wishList = new WishList();
          _wishList.set({
                "ID" : 0,
                "Name" : "",
                "CustomerID" : 106,
                "Type" : 0,
                "LastUpdated" : "\/Date(1383152400000+0700)\/",
                "WishlistDetail" : [
                    {
                        "ID" : 0,
                        "WishListID" : 0,
                        "ItemID" : 22776,
                        "Quantity" : 2,
                        "LastUpdated" : "\/Date(1383152400000+0700)\/"
                    }
                ]
            });
           _wishList.save();

         var _wlView = new WishListView({model:_wishList});
     },
     render : function(){
         this.$el.html(homePanel);
         $("#containernewpromotion").html(promotionItem);
     }
  });
  return HomeView;
});

define(["underscore" , "backbone"], function(_, Backbone){
  var WishListView = Backbone.View.extend({

      tagName: 'ul',

      initialize:function(){
          console.log("initialize wish list view");
      },

      render: function(){

       // this.$el.html("tsest");

// Probably something more like that..
// Notes:
//  - this.$el is already an <UL> element automatically created by Backbone at that point
//  - this.model is our WishList(Model) instance --> _wishList
//  - I'm assuming this method exist: WishList(Model).getWishes() --> Returns the list of wishes inside the list

       this.$el.empty();

       _.each(this.model.getWishes(), function (wishModel) {
         this.$el.append('<li>'+wishModel.get('name')+'</li>');
       });
     }
  });
  return WishListView;
});
```

Comment: How about the `WishList` model?

Comment: I got one error when clicking button : `TypeError: WishList is not a constructor
 

var _wishList = new WishList();`

Comment: The `WishList` Model remains the same. As for `WishList is not a constructor`, you need to include your `WishList` model as a dependency of `HomeView` (see `"app/models/wishlist"` in the code I posted). How you declare that dependency depends on your RequireJS organization/settings/naming/configuration/etc..

Comment: @Domo ..or make your `WishList` model available globally (`window.WishList = ...`), although this is a pretty bad practice (no namespace for your App) and that would negate the use of RequireJS..

Comment: But if it is because of Require.js dependency, why `var _wlView = new WishListView({model:WishList});`, called the `console.log` in my code in my question :/

Comment: Oops , it was because I don't put `return WishList;` in `WishList` model.

Comment: `undefined` result, when I did `console.log(this.model);` in `WishList` view.

Comment: Yeah, that's weird. If you pass `model` to the View contrustor, it should be available inside the view as `this.model` property: [Backbone View constructor Official Documentation](http://backbonejs.org/#View-constructor). So make sure you're either calling `console.log(this.model)` from the right scope, or look for a typo..

Comment: Also you might want update the code in your question to see what's going on now.